# How can I vertically center my nav to the logo?

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment, nav

I am trying to create a header bar with logo on the right, horizontal navigation on the left as usual. I need navigation items to be centered to the logo vertically.

I have tried several methods. I would appreciate if someone could show me the way around and explain why it worked, and what I was probably missing.

```css
body {
  max-width: 995px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Arial';
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #222;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.logo img {
  max-width: 235px;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
}

.menu li {
  display: inline-flex;
  padding-left: 30px;
}

.menu {
  float: right;
}

.nav {
  padding-bottom: 25px;
}

.group:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav group">
  <div class="logo"><img src="img/ahlogo.png" alt="Abdulla Hussain's Logo"></div>
  <div class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li><a href="#thoughts">Thoughts</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      <li><i class="fa fa-facebook social" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: you have any preference on browser support?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you want to align the  navigation to the bottom end of the logo? If yes, you can use `display:flex` with the following settings on the parent element of both:

```
.nav.group {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
```

```css
body {
  max-width: 995px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Arial';
}

.nav.group {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #222;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.logo img {
  max-width: 235px;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
}

.menu li {
  display: inline-flex;
  padding-left: 30px;
}

.menu {
  float: right;
}

.nav {
  padding-bottom: 25px;
}

.group:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav group">
  <div class="logo"><img src="http://placehold.it/120x120/0af" alt="Abdulla Hussain's Logo"></div>
  <div class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li><a href="#thoughts">Thoughts</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      <li><i class="fa fa-facebook social" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Alternatives: If you want to *center-align* them vertically, change `align-items:` to `center;` (or to `top` for top alignment)

```css
body {
  max-width: 995px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Arial';
}

.nav.group {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #222;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.logo img {
  max-width: 235px;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
}

.menu li {
  display: inline-flex;
  padding-left: 30px;
}

.menu {
  float: right;
}

.nav {
  padding-bottom: 25px;
}

.group:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav group">
  <div class="logo"><img src="http://placehold.it/120x120/0af" alt="Abdulla Hussain's Logo"></div>
  <div class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li><a href="#thoughts">Thoughts</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      <li><i class="fa fa-facebook social" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, Johannes! Second option works best, but how do I make sure nav items stay aligned to the right? With justify-content property set to "space-between", nav items are now kind of center aligned.

Comment: I just applied `margin-left: auto` to `.menu` element. Seems to work solve the problem. Is there a better or more practical way of doing this? Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: @Abdulla They *are* right-aligned, but the last item is not visible here in the snippet, since it's a fontawesome-icon that isn't loaded. As soon as that is properly loaded, you should see the right-alignment.

Answer (score 0):

This uses `display:flex` to set items in a line.

If you need to use browsers that do not support `display:flex` (I think IE<9) and you want a different way, let me know.

Open sans included because I like how it looks.

Orange used to demonstrate the middle-ness of the elements.

This will work if you know the height of the logo. If it is unknown, or perhaps changes height (a lot of places have navbars that shrink down a bit once the page scrolls) you may need a different solution.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700');
.nav {
  display: flex;
  background-color: orange;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 50px;
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  font-weight: bold;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.menu ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.menu ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.menu ul li:first-child {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.menu ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav group">
  <div class="logo"><img src="//placehold.it/200x50" alt="Abdulla Hussain's Logo"></div>
  <div class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li><a href="#thoughts">Thoughts</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      <li><i class="fa fa-facebook social" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```